# Is there a way to get only custom registered magics list but not all magic links ( %lsmagic ) in Jupyter notebook / python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipython-magic

There is magic link "%lsmagic" to list all available magic links, I want to list only custom registered magic links.

Is there any way to list only custom magic links?